# Create stacked bar plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am plotting the `foll`. dataframe using pandas:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                       country_name              1960s      1970s        ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ functional_crop_type                                                    ║
║ C3annual              United States of America  48.226957  42.384590    ║
║ C3perennial           United States of America   1.377634   1.377971    ║
║ C4annual              United States of America  32.526747  32.833662    ║
║ C4perennial           United States of America   0.265062   0.289005    ║
║ N-fixing              United States of America  17.603600  23.114773    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝   
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                       1980s      1990s      2000s      2010s       ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ functional_crop_type                                               ║
║ C3annual              41.184368  39.085943  32.821374  28.767468   ║
║ C3perennial            1.413647   1.561404   1.657869   1.691046   ║
║ C4annual              31.260082  32.089138  33.705184  36.815154   ║
║ C4perennial            0.303626   0.367331   0.386495   0.359842   ║
║ N-fixing              25.838277  26.896184  31.429078  32.366490   ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Using the `foll`. command:

```
out_dec_df = out_dec_df.set_index('functional_crop_type')
out_dec_df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

However, I want the `x-axis` to be '1960s', '1970s'...'2010s' and the stacked bar plot to be composed of the functional crop types. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using transpose.

```
out_dec_df.drop('country_name', axis=1).T.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Comment: I did try that earlier, but it tells me that there is no numeric data to plot

Comment: @user308827 can you upload the csv version of your df using `out_dec_df.to_csv()`, so that I can play with the real dataset?

Comment: @user308827 I guess that's because the column `country_name  ` is string, and after transposing, it has no numeric value. try drop that column and then transpose.